# Donations for a new computer taxation help?

Tags: taxes, canada, contribution, donation

I make music on youtube and my equipment is not the greatest. I would like to accept paypal contributions to help me get a better equipment. my question is do i need to declare these donations in my taxes?

I live in canada 
thank you

Comment: Are you a recognized charity or some other special type of taxpayer?

Comment: no its more of a private interest not really a non profit or a charity . i was thinking of using maybe imraising.com

Comment: Is your music-making activity is any way a business? Do you have any other revenue from it, somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare these donations, but each donor may have to declare it as a non-taxable social assistance payment.

**References**

- [Social assistance payments](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/145-eng.html)
- [Other kinds of income](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/130/s-thr-eng.html)

Comment: "based on a means, needs, or income test and include payments for food, clothing, and shelter requirements." - doesn't this imply there's a requirement of 'need'?

Comment: The gift tax link is US based.  I have no idea what you intend with the other links.

Comment: I see now this is another case of necro-bumping.  Just to clarify, there's no tax on gifts in Canada.  You can beg and live tax free.